# set text in a textview based on time android

Tags: android

I want to display a message in a textview, the code that i use right now is

```
mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String str = sdf.format(new Date());

        String[] hr=str.split(":");

        int hr1=Integer.parseInt(hr[0]);

        if(hr1<12)
        {
            mText.setText("it's morning!");
        }else if(hr1>12&& hr1<17)
        {
            mText.setText("it's afternoon!");
        }else if(hr1>17&& hr1<20)
        {
            mText.setText("it's evening!");
        }
```

But that code doesnt work at all it doesnt type anything in the textview.
How do i fix this?

Comment: Your code should work, Put else condition too to check whether your written conditions are correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a null date, you need to get the current time by doing:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // Get current time
int hr1 = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // Gets the current hour of the day from the calendar created ( from 1 to 24 )
```

Check the Calendar documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

Comment: Than you very much mate!

Comment: need to wait four minutes before i can confirm your awnser

Comment: No problem, just keep in mind that Java docs are really helpful you can almost always find the answer for what you need in there!